# How to select the specific radio button by comparing the value (the value is present outside of the tag)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

in the below link
http://www.ironspider.ca/forms/checkradio.htm
i want to select radio button for Opera

But the value is given outside the input tag

```
List<WebElement> radioLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='Content']/div[1]/blockquote[2]/form/input"));
for(WebElement e:radioLinks){
            if(e.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("Opera")){
                e.click();
                break;
            }
```

but Opera is not inside the input tag.

Comment: So what is the problem? Show your code and describe the issue

Comment: yeah i added the code .please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate required `input` by value of the following text node:

```
WebElement operaLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/text()[normalize-space()="Opera"]/preceding::input[1]"));
```

Or simply by index:

```
WebElement operaLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='browser'][3]"));
```

Comment: thanks but how to compare it so that it will select only "Opera radio button"

Comment: This will select only Opera. Why do you need to loop through list of elements instead of clicking on exact `input`?

Comment: the scenario is to click the element based on the label like "opera"

Comment: I don't use any tools. You can check [this](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf) to learn how to create your own `XPath` expressions